# What is the use of the verb "do" in the sentence "Dreams do come true"?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, parts-of-speech

> "Dreams do come true"

How does the word "do" act in the sentence - as an adverb or a helping verb?

Comment: It is an auxiliary  or helping verb for emphasis, often used for contradiction as user 8399 said. Example: You don't know. Answer: Yes, I do (know).

Answer (score 1):

It is a helping verb, like you suppose. *Do + verb* can be used when the speaker want to contradict a presumption that the verb's action is not performed, especially when that presumption has been explicitly stated recently.